# rewrite URL using .htaccess only works on first query string

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

I'm trying to rewrite my url using htaccess but it only worked on the first query string

what I want is to rewrite this URL

```
acnologia.com/index.php?page=images&tag=nature

into something like this acnologia.com/images/nature
```

it does work on the first query string acnologia.com/images
but doesn't work if i add another directory after "images"

this is my .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1&tag=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?page=$1&tag=$2
```

Comment: Where is your $2 defined?

Comment: RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1&tag=$2

Answer (score 0):

The very basic rule will be like this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&tag=$2
```

And more specific will be

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1&tag=$2
```

which @Andrew answered in comment.

Your final rewrite rule should be following. `RewriteCond` is specified so that js, css, png etc. files do not match this rewrite rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1&tag=$2 [L,NC]
```

This [tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache/) is helpful.

Comment: it worked...by adding this line of code RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1&tag=$2

Comment: but i have antoher problem, on the second query string the index file is no longer included

Comment: Could not understand your previous comment. Can you please provide more details?

Comment: Then you need to specify not to overwrite css and js files. I haved added a RewriteCond in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's only one group in your original rule, so there's no $2.

Try this one:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z\d_-]+)/([a-z\d_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1&tag=$2 [NC,L]
```

\d equals 0-9, and NC means nocase